# Why does the call to a parent class constructor not call the parent's methods that are overriden in the child class?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

As shown in the code below, given a superclass `Parent` with a method `calculate()` that is called in `Parent`'s constructor, but also overriden in the class `Child`, why does the implicit call to `Parent`'s constructor within `Child`'s constructor not call `Parent`'s `calculate()` instead of `Child`'s `calculate()`?

```
class Parent {
    Parent() {
        calculate();
        System.out.println("Empty parent ctor.");
    }
    void calculate() {
        System.out.println("Parent calculating...");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    Child() {
        System.out.println("Empty child ctor.");
    }
    @Override
    void calculate() {
        System.out.println("Child calculating...");
    }
}

public class ParentConstructor {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Parent child = new Child();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Child calculating...
Empty parent ctor.
Empty child ctor.
```

I would have thought that to correctly construct a `Parent` object, its constructor should always be called with its own method definitions?

Comment: There are *private* methods for this, they are not inherited.

Comment: You are not constructing a `Parent` object - you are constructing a `Child` object..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method in the parent will never be called by a child or subclass that overrides the method unless you explicitly call it with the super statement. That is because during a method call, which method(parent class or child class) is to be executed is determined by the object type.

This process in which a call to the overridden method is resolved at runtime is known as dynamic method dispatch.

```
class Child extends Parent {
    Child() {
        System.out.println("Empty child ctor.");
    }
    @Override
    void calculate() {
        super.calculate(); // calling parent implementation
        System.out.println("Child calculating...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would have thought that to correctly construct a Parent object, its constructor should always be called with its own method definitions?

No.  It is assumed that if you permit a method to be overridden, and choose to override the method, that the overridden behavior is the right one.

(Methods to prevent this overriding including marking your method final or private.)